# Cannot find grub in ubuntu 23.10 image for editing it

Tags: boot, grub2, live-cd, ubiquity

I was editing Ubuntu 23.04 live CD image to change grub.cfg so that it does not show try and install option. In Ubuntu 23.10 it is not seen anywhere and I cannot edit the live CD. How and where can I change the 23.10 live CD image for removing the Try and install option and other menu options and remove ubiquity?